# In wordpress Chrome & Firefox element Inspector show &nbsp; View source does not, which is correct

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to debug a Wordpress issue where a `&nbsp;` is being auto inserted before the end of the `<script>` tag, hence breaking the javascript.

If I view the element with the inspector, I can see a `&nbsp;` as shown below:
[image]

However if I viewsource, or download the html page and look at it, there is no `&nbsp;`:

```
    });
  });
  setTheRepeaterButton();
  });
</script></p>
```

At first i thought it was a chrome bug, but I get the exact same behaviour in firefox.

I would think there is no `&nbsp;`, however the script is broken which implies there is one. Which is correct, the inspector or the page source?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a hidden/invisible character before the final `}` in the script. Depending on your code editor, you can toggle a setting to view hidden characters or add a plugin (e.g. [nbsp-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=possan.nbsp-vscode) for VS Code).

Or the easiest solution is to delete the space between that `}` and the preceding `;` and redo the code formatting.

Comment: The space actually came from when I ran my friends code through a code beautifier (which then resulted in the code not working). It added spaces to every line, this was the only problem one. I deleted and added the space a few times (copy paste and type), no difference.

Comment: That’s strange. So the mysterious non-breaking space is still there?  Do you have anyway of sharing the code, like a test site or jsbin?